# React component style apply after refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, dropdownchoice

In my react application. I am using a Choice JS library for creating a multi select dropdown. Everything working fine but after enabling the routing in my application when I switch from Home to group component the multi value select dropdown styles are not applying but if I refresh the page then the style is applied.

I added all the required css and js files inside a index.html

```
<div className="mb-3">
    <select
         id="choices-multiple-remove-button"
         placeholder="Select Maximum 5 Members"
         multiple
         onChange={(e) => setGroupUsers(e.target.value)} >
        {userList?.map(user => <option value={user.userId} key={user.userId}>{user.name}</option>)}
    </select>
</div>
```

The options are generating dynamically from the database

Comment: How/Where are the styles defined?

Comment: Inside public folder index.html. Style sheets are added inside the head tag and the scripts are added before the end of body tag

Comment: How are you targeting the element? Class selector/ID selector?

Comment: this usually happens due to style conflicts. consider using more specefic ways to style your components or you may find styles from other pages/compoents are overriding.

Comment: I am not using any custom styling I am using only this library styles and I already my componenet code